# VBA CleanFileName and CleanUsedRange

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am having some issue with the following code. Whenever I run the vba code, the CleanFileName and CleanUsedRange code delete my Vlook formulas.

Is there any way to use the CleanFileName and CleanUsedRange without it deleting the vlook formulas. the codes are below

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Const FULL_PATH = "C:\Documents\test\quot.txt"
Dim fId As String, txt As String, txtLen As Long, d As Object, dc As Long

fId = FreeFile
Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId
    txt = Input(LOF(fId), fId)  'Read entire file (not line-by-line)
Close fId
txtLen = Len(txt)
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d("Name") = "C11"   'Same as: d.Add Key:="Name", Item:="C11"
d("Phone") = "H13"
d("Address1") = "C15"
d("Email") = "C13"
d("Postcode") = "H16"
d("SR") = "C10"
d("MTM") = "H14"
d("Serial") = "H15"
d("Problem") = "C17"
d("Action") = "C18"
d("Dated") = "H10"
dc = d.Count

Dim i As Long, k As String, sz As Long, found As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     '<--- Update sheet name
    For i = 0 To dc - 1     'd.Keys()(i) is a 0-based array
        k = d.Keys()(i)     'Name, Phone, etc
        found = InStr(txt, k) + Len(k) + 1  'Find the (first) key in file
        If found > 0 Then   'Determine item length by finding the next key
            If i < dc - 1 Then sz = InStr(txt, d.Keys()(i + 1)) Else sz = txtLen + 2
            .Range(d(k)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 1))
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

The CleanFile

```
Public Function CleanFileName(ByVal fName As String) As String
Dim b() As Byte, specialChars As Variant, i As Long

b = "\/:*?|<>" & Chr(34) & Chr(8) & Chr(9) & Chr(10) & Chr(13)

specialChars = Split(StrConv(b, vbUnicode), Chr(0))

fName = Trim$(fName)    'Trim, then remove \ / : * ? | < > " Backspace Tab LF CR
For i = 0 To UBound(specialChars)
    fName = Replace(fName, specialChars(i), vbNullString)
Next
CleanFileName = fName
End Function
```

Second code

```
 Public Sub CleanUsedRange(ByRef ur As Range)
Dim arr As Variant, r As Long, c As Long

arr = ur.Formula
For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(r, c) = CleanFileName(arr(r, c))
    Next
Next
ur.Formula = arr
End Sub
```

The export code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, fPath As String, fName As String, dt As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

fPath = "C:\Documents\test\"
dt = Format(Date, " - MM-DD-YYYY")

CleanUsedRange ws.UsedRange

fName = fPath & ws.Range("C10") & dt & " - Quotation"

ws.Range("A1:I60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=fName
End Sub
```

The Vlook formulas are used to import data from another sheet, so that one don't need to type it one by one. Is there a way to twist the cleanfile not to remove vlook formulas.

---

After editing the code as you suggested

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, fPath As String, fName As String, dt As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

fPath = "C:\Users\Documents\test\\"
dt = Format(Date, " - MM-DD-YYYY")

Range("C10") = CleanFileName(Range("C10"))


fName = fPath & ws.Range("C10") & dt & " - Quotation"

ws.Range("A1:I60").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=fName
End Sub
```

However, the exported file appears to have foreigns symbols.. like below

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEGoL.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRYIE.png)

Any other solution?

I have changed the code as you have suggested but i want unable to run the VBA. After adding this:

```
 .Range(d(k)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 2))
```

This is where the error is pointing

```
Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId
```

See picture [new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amxrg.png)

Also find the hex code u requested

[Hex pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUvvC.png)

I have changed the code to

```
 Else sz = txtLen + 3
```

However, I'm still getting error 76 attached [Error 76](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6A9f.png)    And the debug is pointing to this line;

```
 Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your subs `CleanUsedRange()` and `CleanFileName()` are actually deleting (completely) your `Vlook` formulas (whatever they are), but your formulas might get destroyed by `CleanFileName()` as it removes certain characters.

---

To explain why your current code creates problems, let's analyze a few lines:

In `CommandButton2_Click()` you call `CleanUsedRange ws.UsedRange`. Here, `ws` refers to `"Sheet1"` and `UsedRange` represents the used range of `ws`, meaning the range of cells between the first and last columns (inclusive) and first and last rows (inclusive), that have (or have had) content (e.g. data or formulas).

In `CleanUsedRange()` you are traversing all cells (each row and column) of the used range (passed as `ur As Range`) and calling `CleanFileName()` on the content of all these cells. This function (`CleanUsedRange()`) is the main reason for the destruction of your formulas, because it passes the formulas in your worksheet as strings to the `CleanFileName()` function.

In `CleanFileName()`, the passed in argument is checked for certain characters that are invalid in file names. The modified argument is then returned as the result of the function.

---

Fix: Do not pass the whole used range to `CleanUsedRange()` and `CleanFileName()`. In fact you can ditch the `CleanUsedRange()` sub entirly.

Pass only the one cell (C10 ?) that contains the filename that might need cleaning, to `CleanFileName()`.

IOW, in `CommandButton2_Click()` replace

```
CleanUsedRange ws.UsedRange
```

with

```
Range("C10") = CleanFileName(Range("C10")).
```

(Assuming cell `C10` holds the file name to be used.)

---

**Edit concerning "boxed question marks"**

For the problem with the "boxed question marks", I found that any character with code less than 32 produces the problem in a `.pdf` file produced by Excel (in my Excel, only Chr(12) is shown as a "boxed question mark"). Clearly there are two such characters between each field, and the probable ones are a pair of "Carriage Return - Line Feed" (CRLF), but only you can confirm that, as you have not yet provided that information.

When you read the values from the `txt` string you use this code:

```
.Range(d(k)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 1))
```

Changing it to

```
.Range(d(k)).Value2 = Trim$(Mid$(txt, found, sz - found - 2))
```

as I suggested in a comment, cures the problem.

---

**Edit concerning error 7.8.2018**

First, thanks for the file. It clearly confirms my suspicion about a CRLF pair between the fields in the file. It also confirms that the length of the data we extract with the `Mid$()` function must be reduced by 2 instead of 1.

I have not been able to reproduce the error that you experienced with the previous modification, but there is indeed still one error with the last field ("Dated"). Possibly that is raised as an error in your environment, it is not in mine, but the year is erroneously shown as 201.

The error with the last field is that the `sz` variable needs to grow to compensate for the previous change we did in the data extraction (we changed `sz - found - 1` to `sz - found - 2`).

So, change

```
Else sz = txtLen + 2
```

to

```
Else sz = txtLen + 3
```

Of course, this helps only if the error occurs when reading the last field ("Dated") of the file. If this doesn't help, please debug and let me know which field you are reading and what values do the variables `k`, `found` and `sz` have when it fails. Also inform about any popup messages that might show.

Comment: Hi Tom Brunberg, See the comment and pics that i attached. After changing the code as you suggested.. the exported file has foreign characters..

Comment: Those characters appear to have ASCII code 12 (decimal). They are certainly not added due to the code change I suggested, so they must be in your own data, which looks to be imported from somewhere. ASCII code 12 has originally the meaning of "Form Feed", but may have any other meaning in the source of your data, perhaps "field separator". Try to reduce the length of each data item you import, by 1 character, to omit the unwanted Chr(12).

Comment: I have done that but still the same result. The only way the code disappear is if i use "CleanUsedRange ws.UsedRange" and when i replace it with "Range("C10") = CleanFileName(Range("C10"))." it appears.

Comment: Ref. *I have done that but still the same result* How exactly? Please be specific.  Do you have a hex editor? If yes, please load your txt file into the hex editor and take a snapshot of the first 4 lines in the editor with the hex values visible. From where (which program) does your txt file come? Can you make a file available for download?

Comment: At the time of writing, I believe I've answered your actual question regarding deleted/destroyed formulas as well as solved the problem with the "boxed question marks". If the latter is not solved, please, provide the information I requested in my previous comment.

Comment: I changed to the new code you provided but i wasn't able to run the code due to error. I have provided the screen shot

Comment: I have changed the code as u suggested but i am having error 76 and its pointing to Open FULL_PATH For Input As fId

Comment: So, you do know what "Path not found" means, don't you? It has nothing to do with the original question you asked, nor with the code changes I have told you to do. In short: double-check the second line of your posted code: `Const FULL_PATH = "C:\Documents\test\quot.txt"` and correct it as needed. (Hint: in a previous question you had this: `Const FULL_PATH = "C:\Users\Documents\test\customerinformation.txt"` but I don't know if it is correct).

Comment: Thank you @Tom Brunberg .. It works perfectly... Sorry for the path issue I overlooked one of the paths. Everything is working fine now.. Thank you so much,